# what is the value given to data members of the class by default constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

like in java the default value given by constructor is 0, i heard somewhere that in c++ the default value is not given by the constructor but then i made a simple program and print the values of the data members and it print 0 so?

```
    #include<iostream>
    class testclass
    { int value1;
       int value2;
       public :
       void print(){
       std::cout<<value1<<value2;
       } 
       };
       int  main(){
         testclass t1;
         t1.print();
         return 0 ;
      }
```

the above code print 0 as output so...?

Comment: Class data members that do not have their own default constructors, and are not initialized in the class's constructor, have indeterminate initial values. The fact that yours are 0 is coincidence only

Comment: This depends a lot on how you define the variable and where. Handy reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration . As dumb luck and choices made by compiler implementors can make something that's not guaranteed look guaranteed, it's best to leave nothing to chance and know the rules or ensure you've set everything you need set.

Comment: *"i heard somewhere that in c++"* is the wrong way of learning C++. Use a book instead.

Answer (score 0):

> i heard somewhere that in c++ the default value is not given by the constructor but then i made a simple program and print the values of the data members and it print 0 so?

Some compilers might do that but according to the standard, using those member variables is cause for undefined behavior.

Don't count on them. Make sure that your member variables are initialized properly.

Use

```
class testclass
{
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 0;

   ...

};
```

or

```
class testclass
{
   int value1;
   int value2;

   public:
     testclass() : value1(0), value2(0) {}
   ...

};
```